# Can some one explain why the token will always losing words instead of got to the next line?

Tags: c, strtok

```
int fp = open(file_name, O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0644);
if(fp < 0) {
    perror("erro ao abrir o ficheiro");
    _exit(-1);
}
char* notebook = myreadln(fp);
printf("%s\n====\n\n",notebook);
char* token = strtok(notebook, "\n");
while(token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n",token );
    new_line(d,token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}
{...}
```

In this piece of code i load the `char* notebook` with a file so, i wanna split that char* into lines using "\n", but the output is this:

```
Isto vai dar sort
$ ls
Jk isto e que vai
$| sort
Isto faz mais 
$| head -1

====

Isto vai dar sort
        Isto vai dar sort
vai dar sort
        vai dar sort
dar sort
        dar sort
sort
        sort
```

Can some one explain why the token will always losing words instead of going to the next line?

my function new_line:
Data d is a pointer to my struct data

```
void new_line(Data d, char* s){
    char* aux = mystrdup(s);
    printf("\t%s\n",aux);

    int n = conta_palavras(aux); // number of words
    char** args = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char*)); // create space for n words
    args[n] = NULL;

    char** words = escreve_palavras(aux, args);

    add(d,words);

}
```

mystrdup:

```
char * mystrdup (const char *s) {
    if(s == NULL) return NULL;          
    char *d = malloc (strlen (s) + 1); 
    if (d == NULL) return NULL;       
    strcpy (d,s);                    
    return d;                       
}
```

Comment: You would be better splitting it up with `" "` the space char which separates the words. But what does `new_line(d,token);` do? Please show us.

Comment: its updated the question

Comment: Yeah, but you made the code even more complicated than is needed, with `conta_palavras()` and `escreve_palavras()` and `add()`. What don't you like about the simple solution in my answer? Although it does not address the whole of your needs, it shows what is going wrong.

Comment: its wired it not work because `escreve_palavras()` recieve a copy not the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strtok` loop itself is written correctly, and without the function `new_line()` it outputs a single line, because it is breaking the string at the `\n`.

So the function `new_line()` must be interfering with it. Let me guess how. You wanted the string broken into words, and so that is what `new_line()` is attempting to do. When I implement that with the next code - hey! I get the output you got.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void new_line(char *d, char *str)
{
    char *tok = strtok(str, d);
}

int main() {
    char notebook[] = "Isto vai dar sort";
    char delim[] = " ";
    char* token = strtok(notebook, "\n");
    while(token != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", token );
        new_line(delim, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
Isto vai dar sort
vai dar sort
dar sort
sort
```

Now `strtok` is not "reentrant", meaning that if you are using it in one function it cannot be used safely in another function. So let's try to get the answer you wanted by breaking the string at the spaces (and any trailing newline) right away:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char notebook[] = "Isto vai dar sort";
    char* token = strtok(notebook, " \n");    // added the space
    while(token != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", token );
        token = strtok(NULL, " \n");          // added the space
    }
}
```

Now the program output is:

```
Isto
vai
dar
sort
```

which I think is what you wanted.

If you want to use `strtok` in different functions you should use `strtok_s` (MSVC) or `strtok_r` (gcc).